# How to delete and insert data into a same table in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I do a delete for a table in a stored procedure before inserting data into the table?

```
create or replace procedure proc_test is
begin
delete * from table1

insert into table1
select * from table2
end proc_test;
```

Does does not seem to work, what is wrong with the syntax? The error is

```
ERROR at line 8: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with

    << close current delete fetch lock insert
   open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge
   pipe
6. select * from table1
7. 
8. end proc_test;
```

Comment: Define "Does not seem to work"? Does it give an incorrect result? Or does it give a syntax error? Or does a lion jump out of the screen and maul you? Maybe something about `delete * from` not being valid syntax perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the problem was with the missing semicolons! This works

```
create or replace procedure proc_test is
begin
delete * from table1; --semicolon here

insert into table1
select * from table2; --semicolon here
end proc_test;
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for `*` in delete : `delete  from table1`. Also, if you want to delete all records, consider `truncate` (however, `truncate` is ddl command, so you won't be able to rollback)

Comment: delete from does not seem to work either.